# If one instance of CLLocationManager in AppDelegate calls .requestWhenInUseAuthorization(), will another in MapViewController recognize the auth?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

In other words, if I access the location property of the instance of CLLocationManager that has been instantiated in MapViewController, will it provide me with the user's location after authorization has been granted from .requestWhenInUseAuthorization() being called on the instance of CLLocationManager in the app delegate?

Or will it fail?

Comment: This works across the whole application. You are requesting use while the application is in the foreground.

Comment: Yes. But try architect your application to use only one instance of CLLocationManager (wrap it in a singleton or use INTULocationManager)

Comment: Ok I'll make a singleton in the data source